# Building docker images with Jib and Gitlab-CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jib

I am trying to create a pipeline where docker images are created using JIB (via a Maven Plugin) and pushed to my Gitlab Registry.

This works fine locally as I am logged into my docker registry.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <allowInsecureRegistries>true</allowInsecureRegistries>
        <from>
            <image>dockerhost/projectgroup/alpine</image>
        </from>
        <to>
            <image>dockerhost/project/imagename:${project.version}</image>
        </to>
        <container>
            <useCurrentTimestamp>true</useCurrentTimestamp>
        </container>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Say I have a .gitlab-ci.yml which looks like:

```
stages:
  - build_image

build_image:
  stage: build_image
tags:
  - dev
script: |
  mvn compile jib:build
```

Now I am getting an exception when the pipeline is triggered

```
Build image failed: Failed to authenticate with registry dockerhost/projectgroup/alpine because: peer not authenticated
```

I am assuming I am getting this error because I haven't run docker login -u [username] -p [password/token]

How ever I would need a .gitlab-ci.yml which uses a docker-in-docker image to be able to run docker login within my script?

Is there an alternative to using a docker-in-docker image to build this image on my Gitlab CI?

Comment: (1) You don't need docker to run Jib. However, I would assume `dockerhost` where you try to pull from/push to is actually a Docker engine (local or remote).
(2) `peer not authenticated` is an SSL certificate verification issue.

Answer (score 9):

Since GitLab 9.0, all [necessary variables are available by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html):

- `CI_REGISTRY` -- URL of the project registry
- `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` -- "base" image name of the project registry
- `CI_REGISTRY_USER` -- technical user that can access the project registry
- `CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD` -- password/token of that user

As such, you can build and publish an image with this command:

```sh
mvn compile jib:build \
    -Djib.to.auth.username=${CI_REGISTRY_USER} \
    -Djib.to.auth.password=${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} \
    -Djib.to.image=${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
```

You can also use [Maven settings](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-maven-plugin/README.md#using-maven-settings), as you commonly would for authenticating on Maven registries.

Answer (score 2):

Using GitLab you can define secret environement variables that you could use to pass your registry credential to Jib.

1. [Define secret variables using gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#via-the-ui)
2. Pass the registry credential using Jib

   ```
   mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=my-container-image:latest -Djib.to.auth.username=$REGISTRY_USER -Djib.to.auth.password=$REGISTRY_PASSWORD
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For Gradle users:

```
 ./gradlew jib \
 -Djib.to.image=${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest \
 -Djib.to.auth.username=${CI_REGISTRY_USER} \
 -Djib.to.auth.password=${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#authentication-methods calls out using either credential helpers or placing the creds directly in maven settings. Despite calling these "docker credential helpers", I don't think these credential helpers actually use the docker daemon, rather they are just something that stores creds using the appropriate native store and passes it to jib when jib has to authenticate to push the image to a docker API compatible registry.

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#quickstart
Distinguishes building to a docker daemon from building to a registry, so my guess is if you build to a registry you don't need a daemon accessible, which means you just need an image that's capable of running maven.

Of course it's this kind of vague, untested advice that brought you here in the first place right....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

Regarding point one my issue is that as you've said the creds seem to be stored and passed as JIB tries to connect to the registry. Not sure if the docker CLI needs to be available to JIB to do this though.

This is one of the only examples I've found which uses the gitlab registry https://aboullaite.me/gitlab-registry-jib-java/ and it suggests but he's authenticating by using docker login from his local machine. So he's not doing it via the gitlab-ci pipeline.

Comment: In the article, it clearly states that: `I prefer the combination of Maven setting with Maven password encryption to secure the credentials of my private registries.`! So the config should reside on your `settings.xml` as follow:

```
   <server>
      <id>registry.gitlab.com</id>
      <username>Username</username>
      <password>ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD</password>
    </server>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jib with explicit username and passwords.  But note that [Jib does not send passwords over unencrypted connections](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-diagnose-problems-pulling-or-pushing-from-remote-registries) unless explicitly configured with `-DsendCredentialsOverHttp`.