# Maven Jib plugin: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, jib

I am using Maven Jib plugin to deploy my application to Gitlab docker registry. If I use `docker login registry.gitlab.com` and enter username and password I can log in to the gitlab registry successfully. I can see that `~/.docker/config.json` contains the following information:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://registry.gitlab.com": {},
                "registry.gitlab.com": {}
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.2 (darwin)"
        },
        "credsStore": "desktop",
        "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Now if I try to run `mvn -Djib.to.auth.username=${username} -Djib.to.auth.password=${password}  compile jib:build` it fails with the 401 Unauthorized exception. The reason I need to pass the username and password is I would like to run this command in my CICD pipeline and it is required to pass the username and password somehow. I have tested other approaches like setting credentials in the `.m2/settings.xml` or `pom.xml`. None of them works.

Comment: If you've done a `docker login` then you don't need to specify the username or password as jib will use the docker credentials.  Note that Jib must be explicitly configured to send passwords over unencrypted connections with `-DsendCredentialsOverHttp` (sending passwords across open connections is not recommended).

Comment: Did you add `-Djib.to.image=my-image:latest` to your `mvn` command? Also, Gitlab offers the possiblity to save secrets in order to avoid keeping your registry credentials in your .gitlab-ci.yml. See [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032954/9731186).  Another solution is to use `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` to authenticate: `mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Djib.to.auth.username=$CI_REGISTRY_USER -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_JOB_TOKEN`. See [Job token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#job-token)

Comment: After hours of struggle I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695342/5465632) and have added here.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the credential in the jib plugin section as follows

```xml
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>openjdk:8u171-alpine</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>registry.gitlab.com/${project.build.finalName}:${project.version}</image>
                    <auth>
                        <username>${jib.username}</username>
                        <password>${jib.password}</password>
                    </auth>
                </to>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>            
 <build>
```

Have the `jib.username` and `jib.password` as properties in settings.xml.

Note: Adjust the from image as to you need.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As it was mentioned in the question, I have already tested this approach and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Run the maven command with `-X` switch this will print debug information and check.

Comment: It doesn't give much useful information rather than the same 401 unauthorized exception.